# responsive text with bullets above inline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a section with bullets and text appear as below image, when I am trying the text is overlapping over another.[image]

The content place below is dummy some content is small some content is large. I am looking for code only with CSS and HTML (NO BOOTSTRAP)
The code I have written is 
HTML CODE

```
<div>
<span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
<span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
<span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
<span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
<span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
<span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
</div>
```

My CSS CODE:

```
.dot {
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
}
div { text-align:center; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this effect with some [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and the pseudo element [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before). Here are some hints:

- Give the text sections a fixed `width` that longer text can be wrapped
- Position the pseudo element absolute, give it a negative `top` distance and a `left` distance of 50% minus the half of its own width
- Adjust the `margin`/`padding` of the container to your needs

```css
.dot {
  width: 80px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.dot::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 6px);
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}

div {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

body {
  background: #2157d5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
  <span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
  <span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
  <span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
  <span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
  <span class="dot">Hello Hello Hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: blue;
}

.timeline {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 30px 0 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.dot img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dot:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 3px solid;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -25px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.dot:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -20px;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

.bar {
  height: 2px;
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="dot">
    Hello Hello Hello
  </div>
  <div class="dot">
    Hello Hello Hello
  </div>
  <div class="dot">
    Hello Hello Hello
  </div>
  <div class="dot">
    Hello Hello Hello
  </div>
  <div class="dot">
    Hello Hello Hello
  </div>
</div>
```